# Add Gradient color on Plotband highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a line chart on highchart. Is there a way to make the plotBands to have a gradient color?

```
        plotBands: [{
        from: 7,
        to: 0,
        color: 'rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.28)'
    }]
```

Here you can check my code for your reference
**http://jsfiddle.net/MyTestSampleAccount/0nqn5vzs/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like following:

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    plotBands: [{
        color: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 1, y2: 0 },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
            ]
        },
        from: 0,
        to: 7
    }],
},
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0nqn5vzs/1/)

Comment: is it possible to do this with two solid gradient colors?